# Data is not saving in ModelList variable on loop. "Index was out of range"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I know this is a common problem, but i couldn't find the reason.

Model 1:

```
public class BsSingleCategoryProductModel
    {
        public BsSingleCategoryProductModel()
        {
            Products = new List<ProductOverviewModel>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SeName { get; set; }
        public IList<ProductOverviewModel> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Model 2:

```
public class BsMultipleCategoryProductModel
    {

        public BsMultipleCategoryProductModel()
        {
            
            SubCategories = new List<Category>();
            SubCategoriesProduct = new List<BsSingleCategoryProductModel>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SeName { get; set; }
        public IList<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
        public IList<BsSingleCategoryProductModel> SubCategoriesProduct { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my controller Utility Meyhod(Not Action):

```
public string ReturnProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId)
        {
            
            
            var subcategories = _categoryService.GetAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(categoryId, true).ToList();

            
 
            if (subcategories.Count > 0)
            {
                var category = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(categoryId);
                var model = new BsMultipleCategoryProductModel();
                model.SubCategories = subcategories;
                model.Id = category.Id;
                model.Name = category.Name;
                model.SeName = category.GetSeName();
                
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var subcategory in subcategories)
                {
                    model.SubCategoriesProduct[i] = PrepareProductsInCategory(subcategory.Id);
                    i++;
                }
                

                return RenderPartialViewToString("AllProductsInCategoryWithSubcategory", PrepareProductsInCategory(categoryId));

            }else
            {
                return RenderPartialViewToString("AllProductsInCategory", PrepareProductsInCategory(categoryId));
            }
          
        }
```

And here is another method:

```
public BsSingleCategoryProductModel PrepareProductsInCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            var model = new BsSingleCategoryProductModel();
            var category = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(categoryId);
            var categoryIds = new List<int>();
            categoryIds.Add(categoryId);
            IPagedList<Product> products = new PagedList<Product>(new List<Product>(), 0, 1);
            products = _productService.SearchProducts(categoryIds: categoryIds,
                                                    storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id,
                                                   visibleIndividuallyOnly: true);

            
            model.Id = category.Id;
            model.Name = category.Name;
            model.SeName = category.GetSeName();
            model.Products = PrepareProductOverviewModels(products).ToList();

            return model;
        }
```

In the `foreach` loop of `ReturnProductsByCategoryId` method `model.SubCategoriesProduct[i]` is getting that error.

**`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index`**

I did debugging, the values are generating correctly. Whenever the value is trying to insert into `model.SubCategoriesProduct[i]` its showing that error on the first time of the loop. How to fix that? Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
SubCategoriesProduct = new List<BsSingleCategoryProductModel>()
```

creates a list of 0 length. That means that `SubCategoriesProduct[i]` will fail for any `i`, since it tries to access element of a list with no elemens.

For you case you can just do `Add` instead:

```
model.SubCategoriesProduct.Add(PrepareProductsInCategory(subcategory.Id));
```